# Why can't I version compressed/binary files in Stash/Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, nexus

Can some one please advise why cant we store our artifacts or WAR files on stash/bitbucket instead of nexus.

I am bit confused in the difference between stash and other repository like nexus,artifactory etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of opinion as to whether WAR files and other compressed files should be maintained under version control or not. Some organisations store as much as possible in their version control systems: jar files, zip files, binaries; other organisations only version text files where possible.

Personally, I don't think there is any value in storing compressed files like WAR files in git. There are three reasons for this:

- Compressed files are not text files and therefore they can't be merged/diffed or manipulated like normal text files.
- If you are storing a compressed file like a jar or a war file, chances are someone else has already checked the file in somewhere, so over time hundreds of copies of the same file pollute the source tree.
- Over time, your source tree becomes very large, leading to longer checkout times, larger backups and general maintenance headaches.

I think a better approach is to upload the file once to something like nexus (or artifactory), and then pull that file down wherever you need it (usually in a build script).

In some cases you have to version compressed or binary files, there are git solutions for this like [Git LFS](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs)